# How to Secure Resources in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can we secure sqlite database and all asset and drawable Resources in android?
I have tried to convert .png and .jpeg images into webP formate but I think this is not good way to protect resources.Anyone can get resources to rename apk to .zip

Answer (score 0):

You can't really have *secure* resources.

Resources in drawable folders are jpg, png, xml. As you said, you can't protect them against reverse engineering.

One possibility *maybe* is storing encrypted resources not in Drawables but in assets or raw folders. The big disadvantage to this, added to that it not a best practice, is that you must implement a decryption chain to access to each resources and it's very time consuming.